# How do I add keys to a dictionary with existing data?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

The code im trying to create is supposed to have two keys:

["democrats"]
["republicans"]

I've nearly got it with all the correct data, I just don't have the key dictionaries. This is what I'm currently working with:

```py
def getPartyUserTwitterUsage(tweetFile):
    import csv 
    
    myFile = open(tweetFile,"r") # opening file in read
    
    csvReader = csv.reader(myFile,delimiter=",") # splitting for ','
    
    next(csvReader) # skipping header
    
    tweetList = {}
    
    repTweet = 0
    demoTweet = 0
    
    
    for row in csvReader: # iterating through file
        if (row[1] == 'R'):
            if (row[0] not in tweetList):
                tweetList[row[0]] = 1
            else:
                tweetList[row[0]] += 1
        
        
        if (row[1] == 'D'):
            if (row[0] not in tweetList):
                tweetList[row[0]] = 1
            else:
                tweetList[row[0]] += 1

    return tweetList
```

This function:
getPartyUserTwitterUsage("Tweets-2020 (2).csv")

returns:

```
{'ChrisMurphyCT': 1000,
 'SenBlumenthal': 1000,
 'SenatorCarper': 1000,
 'ChrisCoons': 1000,
 'brianschatz': 1000,
 'maziehirono': 1000,
 'SenatorDurbin': 1000,
 'SenatorHarkin': 1000,
 'lisamurkowski': 1000,
 'JeffFlake': 1000,
 'marcorubio': 1000,
 'MikeCrapo': 958,
 'SenatorRisch': 1000,
 'ChuckGrassley': 1000,
 'SenPatRoberts': 1000,
 'JerryMoran': 1000}
```

This is the output im expecting:

```
{'Republicans': {'lisamurkowski': 1000,
  'JeffFlake': 1000,
  'marcorubio': 1000,
  'MikeCrapo': 958,
  'SenatorRisch': 1000,
  'ChuckGrassley': 1000,
  'SenPatRoberts': 1000,
  'JerryMoran': 1000},
 'Democrats': {'ChrisMurphyCT': 1000,
  'SenBlumenthal': 1000,
  'SenatorCarper': 1000,
  'ChrisCoons': 1000,
  'brianschatz': 1000,
  'maziehirono': 1000,
  'SenatorDurbin': 1000,
  'SenatorHarkin': 1000}}
```

Comment: Please kindly show some first line (i.e. first 5 rows) of csv, because it might be hard to figure out how to help you.

Comment: To create a key/value pair in a Python dictionary, you just need to do `your_dictionary[<the_key_you_want>] = <default_value>`. For instance, if you wanted to have `"Republicans"` and `"Democrats"` as keys in a dictionary named `test_dict`, and the values associated with these keys to be dictionaries themselves, you would do `test_dict["Republicans"] = {}` and `test_dict["Democrats"]`. If you want to know how to sort your data in these dictionaries, please do as @DhanaD. suggested and post some of your data.

Comment: Use `tweetList  = defaultdict(dict)`. And then use two keys to add data into your dict: `tweetList[row[1]][row[0]] = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the keys: `Republicans` and `Democrats` before inserting the entries.

```
...
    tweetList["Republicans"] = {}
    tweetList["Democrats"] = {}
    for row in csvReader: # iterating through file
        if (row[1] == 'R'):
            if (row[0] not in tweetList["Republicans"]):
                tweetList["Republicans"][row[0]] = 1
            else:
                tweetList["Republicans"][row[0]] += 1
        
        
        if (row[1] == 'D'):
            if (row[0] not in tweetList["Democrats"]):
                tweetList["Democrats"][row[0]] = 1
            else:
                tweetList["Democrats"][row[0]] += 1

    return tweetList
```